# Does the interval of a portfolio's returns affect Sharpe and Sortino? If so, what's the gold-standard interval?

Tags: risk, sharpe-ratio, asset-returns, ratio

I'm currently creating a backtesting script and I've got to the point of calculating risk metrics.

It seems like the interval (daily, weekly, or monthly) I use for returns heavily changes the outputted Sharpe and Sortino ratios.

---

I have date for daily returns between `2018-08-31` and `2021-08-31`.

The risk-free rate I've used is `1.36%` annually.

---

#### Daily

Sharpe: `0.14`
Sortino: `0.30`

#### Weekly

Sharpe: `0.26`
Sortino: `0.95`

#### Monthly

Sharpe: `0.53`
Sortino: `4.79`

---

If this difference is to be expected, what's the gold-standard interval in the industry?

If this difference isn't expected, what errors may have occurred to cause it?

NB: The returns are *extremely* volatile and I'm guessing this may be the root cause.

Comment: Are you annualizing/rescaling your metrics? That would be the first thing to check, however, even if you do that, they will still be different. See : https://alo.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/The-Statistics-of-Sharpe-Ratios.pdf for a great discussion.

Comment: @rubikscube09 - wow, I totally forgot about that! Is it best to annualize from daily? And does the same apply for Sortino?

Comment: The annualized values of Sharpe will be $0.14 \sqrt{252},0.26 \sqrt{52},0.53 \sqrt{12}$ or 2.22, 1.87, 1.83 respectively. They are fairly consistent with each other.